# parse string object without using JSON

Tags: javascript, parsing

I need to parse an object from html element attribute (like angular does it) without using JSON.parse or something

For example I have a `DIV` like this

```
<div some-attribute="{key1: 1 > 0, key2: true || false}"></div>
```

And after parsing I need just string representation of all that I have in this object:

```
{'key1': '1 > 0', 'key2': 'true || false'}
```

Is there any ability to parse it this way without inventing a new parser?

Comment: When evaluated as Javascript, the value of the `some-attribute` attribute produces a different object than the one you posted below the HTML code.

Comment: _"without using JSON.parse"_ - why? Use double quotes and you'll have what you want

Comment: Just break it up into separate attributes.

Comment: @axiac i can't evaluate it, there can be some object methods callings

Comment: @evolutionxbox i can't use double quotes

Comment: @TravisJ i need to keep it in a single attribute

Comment: `{key1: 1 > 0, key2: true || false}` is the same as `{key1: true, key2: true}` which is completely different than `{'key1': '1 > 0', 'key2': 'true || false'}`. The properties of the first object have boolean values (`true`), they are strings on the second object.

Comment: Why can't you use double quotes?

Comment: @axiac it's just an example. there can be any expression, and it will be evaluated later

Comment: @evolutionxbox if i can, i wouldn't ask a question here, mate

Comment: Come on, I'm asking a relevant question. --- If you're asking for us to provide a "parsing library" that's off-topic.

Comment: @dimaninc There is a difference between `parse string object without using JSON` and `there can be any expression, and it will be evaluated later` - If you intend to pass expressions and **not** objects for later evaluation/execution it might be better to post one of those expressions and how you intend to evaluate them later as in that case a HTML attribute might not be the best place for it to begin with.

Comment: My point is that you ask how to evaluate `2+2` but instead of `4` you expect to get `'2'+'2'`.

Comment: Someone mentioned `eval` ... <closes door> `I'm out of here, not touching that, you are on your own now` :)

Comment: @dimaninc You mentioned Angular, did you look at the [source](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/parse.js) ?

Comment: I realise after re-reading that eval isn't what OP needs anyway :p

Comment: @SergeK.thanks for the link, i think i will use some code from it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all guys, I realized that I should just create a parser for this. This is the first version (on Coffee, not pure JS)

```
class Parser
    self = @

    constructor: ->

    @quotes: '\'"`'

    @object: (dataStr) ->
        dataStr = $dp.fn.trim dataStr
        if dataStr[0] isnt '{' or dataStr.slice(-1) isnt '}'
            return null
        dataStr = dataStr.slice 1, dataStr.length - 1

        o = {}
        pair =
            key: ''
            value: ''
        addPair = ->
            o[$dp.fn.trim(pair.key)] = $dp.fn.trim pair.value
            pair.key = pair.value = ''
        quoteOpened = null
        underCursor = 'key'

        for ch, i in dataStr
            skip = false

            if ch in self.quotes
                unless quoteOpened
                    quoteOpened = ch
                    skip = true
                else if quoteOpened and ch is quoteOpened
                    quoteOpened = null
                    skip = true

            unless quoteOpened
                switch
                    when ch is ':'
                        underCursor = 'border'
                    when underCursor is 'border' and not /\s/.test ch
                        underCursor = 'value'
                    when ch is ','
                        underCursor = 'key'
                        addPair()
                        skip = true

            pair[underCursor] += ch if underCursor isnt 'border' and not skip

        addPair() if pair.key or pair.value
        o
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you want to get the `[Object]` finally? You can search for `,` and `:` in the [String] value and then split it like this:

```js
//retrieve this from attribute with DOM methods
var a = "{key1: 1 > 0, key2: true || false}";

console.log(parse(a));

function parse(data) {
  if (data[0] !== '{' || data[data.length - 1] !== '}') return null; //remove it if useless
  var props = data.slice(1, data.length - 1).split(/\s*,\s*/);
  var newObj = {};
  props.forEach((a) => {
    var pair = a.split(/\s*:\s*/);
    newObj[pair[0]] = pair[1];
  });
  return newObj;
}
```

The `RegExp` removes spaces between `,` and `:`

Comment: and what if there is a comma in key? like `{'key1,key7': 1 > 0}`

Comment: There must be some restrictions, even Angular has a lot when it comes to constructing `{{ ... }}` expressions. This is not AI :)